# Symfony problem join(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given

Tags: php, symfony

I'm a beginner trying to learn symphony and I have a problem when I use

> php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load

It tells me

> In Base.php line 429:

> join(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given

But I don't have any file name Base.php in my project.

There is my code

```
    $modeles = [$modele1,$modele2,$modele3,$modele4,$modele5];


    $faker = \Faker\Factory::create('fr_FR');
    foreach($modeles as $m){
        $rand = rand(3,5);
        for($i=1; $i <= $rand; $i++){
            $voiture = new Voiture();
            $voiture->setImmatriculation($faker->regexify("[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3,4}[A-Z]{2}"))
                ->setNbPortes($faker->randomElement($array = array(3,5)))
                ->setAnnee($faker->numberBetween($min=1990,$max=2019))
                ->setModele($m);
            $manager->persist($voiture);
        } 
    }
    $manager->flush();
}
```

Comment: Whats your version of faker bundle ?

Answer (score 0):

you can go there by this:  direction: Faker/src/Faker/Provider/Base.php

in line of 429:
return join(range($range[1], $range[2]), '');

you can change it by:

return join('',range($range[1], $range[2]));

and it should be done!